# Implementing Hibernate in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate in Play for Scala. I added a file `hibernate.cfg.xml` to `conf/META-INF` but apparently Play doesn't find it as I get the error:

> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource
>   [hibernate.cfg.xml]]]
>           at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
>           at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
>           at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
>           at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
>           at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
>           at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)

This is the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, where should I put it?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sap://10.194.19.20:39013</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">uuu</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the xml file to conf, not conf/META-INF